# Typescript strict types and rxjs filter and map combination

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have stumbled upon a situation and I am seeking feedback.

Given the following code,

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { first, map } from "rxjs/operators";

type Something = {
  prop: number;
};

const source = new Subject<Something | undefined>();

source.asObservable().pipe(
  first((value) => !!value),
  map((value) => {
    console.log(value.prop);
  })
);
```

The type of the value on the `map` operator is still `Something | undefiend`, but we are sure we won't get any `undefined` since we are filtering by truthiness.

What's the best approach to handle this scenario, without having to check for truthiness of the value inside the map operator?

Dependencies:

```
rxjs@7.5.2
typescript@4.5.5
```

tsconfig

```
strict: true
```

Comment: It's not showing `undefined` when I try this on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-rbommf?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Comment: @martin That's because you don't have `strictNullChecks` on your stackblitz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a type guard for that:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { filter, first, map } from "rxjs/operators";

type Something = {
  prop: number;
};

const source = new Subject<Something | undefined>();

function isDefined<T>(arg: T | null | undefined): arg is T {
    return arg !== null && arg !== undefined;
  }
  
source.asObservable().pipe(
  first(isDefined),
  map((value) => {
    console.log(value.prop);
  })
);
```

Comment: Yes, great! There is an overload of `first` that takes a type guard as a predicate - there is one for `filter` too. Hadn't noticed!

Comment: Note: you can also use [ts-is-defined](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-is-defined) that provides an isDefined type guard in the same way as described in this answer.

Comment: I don't know if I would recommend adding a dependancy that has it's own dependancy for a simple function like this.